# RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#5485a relayoutBoundary=up15 NEEDS-PAINT

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, gridview, firebase-storage

I want to show images from firebase by using gridview.builder i don't know it create this error
Error is:
**"RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#5485a relayoutBoundary=up15 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 2001 pos 12: 'hasSize'"**

This is my code:-

```
StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Add_product").snapshots(),
              builder:(BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>snapshot){
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(child: LoadingAnimationWidget.staggeredDotsWave(color: Colors.red, size: 10));
                }
                return Container(
                  child: GridView.builder(gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    childAspectRatio: 1.0,

                  ),
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (itemBuilder,index){
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(color:Colors.yellowAccent,backgroundColor: Colors.yellow.shade200,),);
                    }
return Container(
    child: Card(
         elevation: 3,
      shadowColor: Colors.yellow,
      child: Image.network(snapshot.data!.docs[index]["url"]),
                    ));
                  }),
                );

              } ,

            ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `GridView.builder` use, `shrinkWrap`.

```
GridView.builder(
  shrinkWrap:true,
  //rest of your code
  ),
```